# Any suggestion how to display the portion of a text bold inside a MultiCell n FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf, bold

I am using FPDF latest version for creating pdf files in php. The task which i want to perform is that i have values stored in database with html bold tags inside them that is some text is present inside html b tag (properly inside opening and closing tags). I want to display the text inside those b tags as bold in a MultiCell.

Any suggestion how to display the portion of a text bold inside a MultiCell.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Fpdf Multicell add-on](http://interpid.eu/fpdf-multicell)

Answer (score 0):

If you are satisfied with similar solution without using MultiCell(), then no need to use Diego's suggestion, because you need to pay at least 20 EUR for that solution.

I've already answered this with only a few lines of code in [FPDF - Inline bold text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697527/fpdf-inline-bold-text/45889693#45889693)

You can easily modify the Rect() width and height with math to contain your database values.

Answer (score 0):

There's a "**Free**" Version of FDPF Multicell Add-On

[Pascal Morin Version](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script23.php)