# FPDF - Inline bold text

Tags: php, html, border, fpdf

I am trying to create a PDF from PHP and for legal reason we need to make part of our disclaimer BOLD and the disclaimer needs to be outlined.

My current code uses:

```
if(isset($_POST['optout']) && $_POST['optout'] == "yes"){
    $pdf->Ln(5);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',12);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(128);
    $pdf->MultiCell(0,4,'This is my disclaimer. THESE WORDS NEED TO BE BOLD. These words do not need to be bold.',1,'C');
}
```

I am currently using WriteHTML for other parts of the document, and I could easily use that instead of MultiCell, but then how do I create the border?

So I have 2 options..

**native FPDF functions**

PROS: Give an option for a border

CONS: No easy way to make inline text bold

**WriteHTML extension class**

PROS: Lets me easily add bold text inline

CONS: Not sure how to create the border

Suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could rewrite a part of the extension but it may be easier for you to use the extension writeHTML, then draw a cell (empty text) with a border over the cell you created with writeHTML. By adjusting your cells properly it should work.

Don't forget to use SetY **then** SetX to position your cells.

Example:

```
if(isset($_POST['optout']) && $_POST['optout'] == "yes"){
   $pdf->Ln(5);
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',12);
   $pdf->SetTextColor(128);

   //Your text cell
   $pdf->SetY($pos_Y);
   $pdf->SetX($pos_X);
   $pdf->writeHTML('This is my disclaimer. <b>THESE WORDS NEED TO BE BOLD.</b> These words do not need to be bold.');

   //Your bordered cell
   $pdf->SetY($pos_Y);
   $pdf->SetX($pos_X);
   $pdf->Cell($width, $height, '', 1, 0, 'C');
 }
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, except I used `Rect()` instead of cell. Thank you.

Comment: When I write "<p align='center'><b> Word 1:</b> Word 2</p>" it is creating a line break between Word 1 and Word 2, how to fix that?

Comment: how about MultiCell ?

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I solved it:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$cell = 'This is my disclaimer.';
$pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth($cell),3,$cell, 0, 'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$boldCell = "THESE WORDS NEED TO BE BOLD.";
$pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth($boldCell),3,$boldCell, 0, 'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$cell = 'These words do not need to be bold.';
$pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth($cell),3,$cell, 0, 'L');
```

Essentially, make one cell, change font, then another cell with the width of the text you want to bold, and so on.

There seem to be better tools out there for making PDFs that use HTML / Blade templates and such, though, so you might want to consider using that.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Write() & Rect()](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/index.php).

Example:

```
$pdf->Rect($pdf->GetX(),$pdf->GetY(),2,0.1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->Write(0.1,"this is not bold, but this ");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
$pdf->Write(0.1,"is bold.");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->Ln();
```

You need to play around with width & height of the Rect() parameters. In this case, I set width = 2 and height to 0.1 [User Units](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/__construct.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org) supports writing Cell containing HTML via [writeHTMLCell()](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_007/), syntax [here](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/tcpdf.php#L17079).

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell($width, $height, $x, $y, "<b>bold</b> and <u>underlined</u> text.");
```

Answer (score 0):

I find other soluction.

http://fpdf.de/downloads/add-ons/tag-based-formatting.html

copy and paste fragment code write_tag inside file fpdf.php, call function write_tag while was create of pdf, whit this I can make format at the text in pdf.

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF more useful than FPDF

In TCPDF

If you set the **$ishtml** parameter to **true** in multicell, you can adapt the html properties to your texts.

```
$text = "It <b>must</b> be like that";

$this->MultiCell($w, $h, $text, $border, $align, $fill, $ln, $x, $y, $reseth, $stretch, true, $autopadding, $maxh);
```

Default function;

```
MultiCell($w, $h, $txt, $border=0, $align='J', $fill=0, $ln=1, $x='', $y='', $reseth=true, $stretch=0, $ishtml=false, $autopadding=true, $maxh=0)
```

Function you need to do

```
MultiCell($w, $h, $txt, $border=0, $align='J', $fill=0, $ln=1, $x='', $y='', $reseth=true, $stretch=0, $ishtml=true, $autopadding=true, $maxh=0)
```

I hope it helps..

Comment: answering a question that's more than half a decade old... bold move.

Comment: Kind of wrestling with a dead bear :-p